# running Guard rspec for ruby kata

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

So i'm trying to use guard rspec just for ruby, and not for rails.  The test runs fine but the only problem is that it only looks for the spec.rb file, and doesn't look for the actual file. So I have a failed arabic_to_roman.rb and arabic_to_roman_spec.rb.  the Guardfile is installed under the directory roman_numerals_kata.  It only looks for the _spec.rb file and not the arabic_to_roman.rb. here is what the Guardfile looks like

```
  1 # A sample Guardfile
  2 # More info at https://github.com/guard/guard#readme
  3 
  4 guard 'rspec' do
  5   watch(%r{^spec/.+_spec\.rb$})
  6   watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$})     { |m| "spec/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  7   watch('spec/spec_helper.rb')  { "spec" }
  8 
  9   # Rails example
 10   watch(%r{^app/(.+)\.rb$})                           { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
 11   watch(%r{^app/(.*)(\.erb|\.haml)$})                 { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}#     {m[2]}_spec.rb" }
 12   watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_(controller)\.rb$})  { |m| ["spec/routing/#  {m[1]}_routing_spec.rb", "spec/#{m[2]}s/#{m[1]}_#{m[2]}_spec.rb", "spec/acceptance/#{m[1]}_spec.rb"] }
 13   watch(%r{^spec/support/(.+)\.rb$})                  { "spec" }
 14   watch('config/routes.rb')                           { "spec/routing" }
 15   watch('app/controllers/application_controller.rb')  { "spec/controllers" }
 16 
 17   # Capybara features specs
 18   watch(%r{^app/views/(.+)/.*\.(erb|haml)$})          { |m| "spec/features/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
 19 
 20   # Turnip features and steps
 21   watch(%r{^spec/acceptance/(.+)\.feature$})
 22   watch(%r{^spec/acceptance/steps/(.+)_steps\.rb$})   { |m| Dir[File.join("**/#{m[1]}.feature")][0] || 'spec/acceptance' }
23 end
24
```

Answer (score 2):

What is the structure of your directory?

Based on this config, Guard looks for any ruby files in the lib directory and will execute the matching test that is nested inside spec/lib/.  Those details are in this line of the guardfile: `watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$})     { |m| "spec/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }`.

Using this Guardfile (which matches my standard project layout) you should have the following folder layout:

```
BASE_DIR
├── Guardfile
├── lib
│   ├── README
│   └── arabic_to_roman.rb
├── spec
│   ├── lib
│   │   └── arabic_to_roman_spec.rb
│   └── spec_helper.rb
```

The alternative, if not wishing to conform to standard folder layout is to modify the Guardfile like this

```
guard 'rspec' do
  watch(%r{^spec/.+_spec\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^(.+)\.rb$})     { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb')  { "spec" }
end
```

Notice that the second `watch` command is looking for it in the basedir rather than in `lib/*`

Hope this helps :)

Comment: the directory structure is 
arabic_numerals_kata
  Guardfile
  arabic_to_roman.rb

  spec
     arabic_to_roman_spec.rb

This should be fine right?  Also I figured out that If i write the codes in the arabic_to_roman_spec.rb file it works.  so it seems like its only scanning the _spec file and not the actual arabic_to_roman.rb file for some reason.

Comment: The arabic_to_roman.rb should be nested inside a `lib` folder for it to watch, based on the Guardfile settings.  Alternatively change the line in the Guardfile to this: `watch(%r{^(.+)\.rb$})     { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }`.  I'd recommend mimicking the default folder layout though as indicated in my answer rather than tweaking the guardfile as I just did.

Comment: When this solves your problem, please mark question as answered to help future people asking a similar question.